# Read text data from a website

Tags: python, url, recursion

My program recursively processes a string to reverse it.  I would like to have it pull data directly from the website instead of a text file as it currently does, but I can't get it to pull the data from the website.

```
import urllib.request

def reverse(alist):
    #print(alist)
    if alist == []:
        return []
    else:
        return reverse(alist[1:]) + [alist[0]]

def main():
    #file1 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://devel.cs.stolaf.edu/parallel/data/cathat.txt').read()
    file1 = open('cat.txt','r')
    for line in file1:
        stulist = line.split()
        x = reverse(stulist)
        print(' '.join(x))
    file1.close()

main()
```

The commented-out lines are to show what I have tried.

Comment: If you're trying to parse html try using the package "BeautifulSoup".
It is pip installable ie. ```pip install beautifulsoup```.

Comment: Questions should be specific, have definite answers, and very little ambiguity (ideally, none). What are you trying to ask?

Comment: http://devel.cs.stolaf.edu/parallel/data/cathat.txt The txt file at this link is what I'm attempting to read

Comment: the line `def reverse(alist):` is not indented properly, shift it to the left.

Comment: That's just a error copying and pasting the program works I just can't get it to use the text from the site

Comment: currently my code is what I posted originally without the ".read()" at the end of line 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the url normally as a file:

```
import urllib
...
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
for line in f:
    ...
f.close()
```

What you did was to call `read` on the opened url. So you read all the content into `file1` variable and `file1` became a string.

For python 3:

```
import urllib.request
...
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
for line in f:
    ...
f.close()
```

Also you need to convert each line to the correct encoding. If the encoding is `utf-8` then you can do the following:

```
for line in f:
    line = line.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: when I do that I get: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: doesnt work either :( AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found Thats my current error

Comment: currently my code is the same as what I posted without the '.read()' at the end of line 10

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help! It'd be nice if my prof explained anything he wanted us to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2

def reverse(alist):
    if alist == []: 
        return []
    else:
        return reverse(alist[1:]) + [alist[0]]

def main():

    lines = [line.strip() for line in urllib2.urlopen('http://devel.cs.stolaf.edu/parallel/data/cathat.txt')]
    print lines
    print lines[::-1]
main()
```

Output

```
['The cat in the party hat', 'wore the hat', 'to the cat hat party.']
['to the cat hat party.', 'wore the hat', 'The cat in the party hat']
```

Comment: I tried that earlier but I get: ImportError: No module named 'urllib2' Apparently that module comes with python but I don't seem to have it on python 3.4.3

Comment: @DeandreYuselfBauswell - This is because you are using `Python3`. `urllib2` is split across multiple modules in `Python 3.x` .Use the above answer to access your file.